# It should be possible to remove your own edit from the review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just edited a questions formatting (code tag was used incorrectly).

That question has been edited just now to look exactly like the edit I made. It will make no sense to the reviewers and just waste time.

Answer (score 4):

Your edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11995192), as it should have been.

You are incorrect when you state the code format was used incorrectly. In the code block, there is a method named `callMethod`. The sentence itself makes it clear the user is referring to this method. It was properly emphasized as code.

Additionally, you removed an apostrophe from a contraction, making it look like the user had a typo, removed white space at the beginning of the post but left in the "I'm not sure how to deal with this noise", and added "Thanks" to the post. Basically, you did everything wrong with this edit.

If you can't introduce a 6 character change into the post, don't make errors and noise so that it gets into the queue. Find a post that really needs an edit. There are plenty.

Slow down  when adding or removing backticks. Your removal was not justified and quickly reading the sentence would have shown the user was referring to a method in the code.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that when HopefullyHelpful says "code tag was used incorrectly", they mean in the [original revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36585752/1) where you can see a stray backtick preceding the unformatted code block. HopefullyHelpful corrected that alone, but it conflicted with [PM 77-1's edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36585752/2) which corrected all the writing issues you mention *along with* fixing the code block, making it seem as though HopefullyHelpful's edit was actively making the post worse.

Comment: And HopefullyHelpful is *well aware* of this misleading impression - hence their FR to redact a suggested edit that they know is no longer applicable due to a conflict. (I don't quite understand how suggested edit conflicts work tbh, and so I can't explain why this suggestion was made available to reviewers rather than auto-rejected.)